Lagrangian Density for a Non-Relativistic Fluid
Let us consider a non-relativistic particle of mass $m$ immersed in a Riemannian manifold and subject to some external potential $U$. The Lagrangian function $L$ for this system is
$$L(q, \dot{q}, t) = \frac{1}{2}mg_{ij}\dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j - U(q, \dot{q}, t) \tag{1}$$
We now wish to extend this situation to a system of $n$ interacting particles. The Lagrangian function we want is
$$L(q_{(1)}, \dot{q}_{(1)}, \dots, q_{(n)}, \dot{q}_{(n)}, t) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{2}m_{(i)}g_{jk}\dot{q}_{(i)}^j\dot{q}_{(i)}^k - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n V_{(i, j)}(q_{(i)}, \dot{q}_{(i)}, q_{(j)}, \dot{q}_{(j)}, t) - \sum_{i = 1}^n U_{(i)}(q_{(i)}, \dot{q}_{(i)}, t) \tag{2}$$
where we have introduced parentheses to distinguish particle labels from indices, $V_{(i,j)}$ are interaction potentials satisfying $V_{(i, j)} = V_{(j, i)}$, and $U_{(i)}$ are external potentials.
My question is about the continuum limit of the Lagrangian function in $(2)$. Let us restrict to the case of non-interacting dust, i.e. $V_{(i, j)} = 0$ and $U_{(i)} = 0$, for the sake of simplicity. Then $(2)$ becomes
$$L(q_{(1)}, \dot{q}_{(1)}, \dots, q_{(n)}, \dot{q}_{(n)}, t) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{2}m_{(i)}g_{jk}\dot{q}_{(i)}^j\dot{q}_{(i)}^k \tag{3}$$
The corresponding action functional $S$ is
$$S[q_{(1)}, \dots, q_{(n)}] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L\bigg(q_{(1)}, \frac{dq_{(1)}}{dt}, \dots, q_{(n)}, \frac{dq_{(n)}}{dt}, t\bigg) dt \tag{4}$$
$$= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{2}m_{(i)}g_{jk}\frac{dq_{(i)}^j}{dt}\frac{dq_{(i)}^k}{dt} dt \tag{5}$$
Let us imagine a system with an enormous number of particles spaced closely enough together that we can treat the bulk as a continuous fluid. Then, heuristically, we just promote the sum over particles to an integral over space. Perhaps something like:
$$S[q_{(1)}, \dots, q_{(n)}] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\Omega} \rho_mg_{ij}u^iu^j \sqrt{|g|} dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^d dt \tag{6}$$
where we absorbed a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ into the overall normalization of the action functional, $\rho_m$ is the mass density of the fluid, and $u$ is the velocity field of the fluid. We see that the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$ corresponding to $(6)$ is then
$$\mathcal{L}(\rho_m, \nabla\rho_m, \partial_t\rho_m, u, \nabla u, \partial_t u, x, t) = \rho_mg_{ij}u^iu^j\sqrt{|g|} \tag{7}$$
My question is whether this result is correct. If not, why? Is there a simple, systematic approach that allows us to take $(2)$ to its corresponding continuum limit that does not involve the heuristic argument that we used to reach $(6)$?
